# Generic message system using variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, template, generics, variadic

in my spare time I´m creating a hobby game engine as decided to write some of my systems on my own. As the time passes I´ve decided to start publishing it as a independent libraries for use (so anybody can use it), the first one is my message system. The main task was simple : create a flexible system that allowed me to create a different types of the messages even during the runtime. For this I used the modern c++ features such as variadic templates, lambdas, smart pointers (to minimalize the memory leaks). I used an RTTI (typeid) because of the mechanism for detecting the given parameters when listening/binding to a message.

Some simple idea is :

1. Create a messages, save their hash(representing the variadic parameters) - via the **createMessage** function
2. Bind a functions to messages (when binding function, check the functions parameters if it fits the parameters that were given to created message) - via the **bindFunction**
3. Broadcast messages

For simplicity i defined it as a single-header library because of the ease of the compilation and portability. It is written in OOP, messages are created only via the itnerface from main class, **MessageManager**(static class at the moment) and listening+broadcasting is made via the objects called **MessageHandlers**.

```
    #pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

namespace pin
{
    const std::string PIN_BLANK = "Blank";

    //Variadic function wrapper
    template<class... Args>
    class variadicFunction
    {
        private:
            //Functor
            std::function<void(Args...)> _function;

        public:
            variadicFunction() {};

            template<class T>
            void bindFunction(void(T::*function)(Args... args), T* ownerPtr)
            {
                //Saved via lambda to avoid generic placeholders with std::bind
                _function = [function, ownerPtr](Args... args)
                {
                    (ownerPtr->*function)(args...);
                };
            }

            void exec(Args&&... args)
            {
                if (_function)
                    _function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
    };

    //Base class for parameter pack so its able to combine it with polymorphism
    class base_param_pack{};

    //Variadic parameter pack
    template<class... Args>
    class param_pack{};

    class BaseMessage
    {
    protected:
        //Text of the message
        std::string _messageText;

        //Hash generated to check the type of the passed parameter pack
        std::size_t _parameterHash;

    protected:

        //Hashing function
        template <class... Args>
        void createHash()
        {
            //Create temporary parameter pack class from our passed arguments
            param_pack<Args...> tmpPack;

            //Save the ID of the pack using the RTTI
            _parameterHash = typeid(tmpPack).hash_code();

        }

    public:
        //Default constructor
        BaseMessage() :
            _messageText(PIN_BLANK),
            _parameterHash(0)
        {}

        //Constructing with the message name
        BaseMessage(const std::string& messageName) :
            _messageText(messageName),
            _parameterHash(0)
        {}

        virtual ~BaseMessage() {};

        virtual void clearListeners() = 0;

        //Checking the parameter hashes
        bool haveSameParameterHash(const std::size_t& paramHash)
        {
            return (_parameterHash == paramHash);
        }

        //Setting the message text
        void setMessageText(const std::string& text) { _messageText = text; }
        const std::string& getMessageText() { return _messageText; }
    };

    template <class... Args>
    class Message :public BaseMessage
    {
        typedef std::pair<bool*, variadicFunction<Args...>> listener;
    private:

        //Vector of listeners represented as variadic functions
        std::vector<listener> _listeners;

    protected:

        //Function checking if the listener exists or not
        bool isValidListener(const listener& listener)
        {
            return (listener.first);
        }

        void clearListeners() override
        {
            //Erase-remove idiom
            _listeners.erase(std::remove_if(
                                            _listeners.begin(),
                                            _listeners.end(),
                                            [](const listener& listener) 
                                            {
                                                return !*listener.first;
                                            }
                                            ),
                            _listeners.end());
        }

    public:

        Message():
        {
            createHash();
        }

        Message(const std::string& messageName) :
            BaseMessage(messageName)
        {
            createHash<Args...>();
        }

        //Broadcasting the message - no check if the parameter pack sets the hash
        void broadcast(Args&&... args)
        {
            for (auto& listener : _listeners)
            {
                listener.second.exec(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        }

        //Binding the function listener - no check if the parameter pack sets the hash
        template<class T, class... Args2>
        void bindFunction(bool* handler, void(T::*function)(Args2... args), T* ownerPtr)
        {
            _listeners.emplace_back();

            _listeners.back().first = handler;

            _listeners.back().second.bindFunction(function, ownerPtr);
        }
    };

    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<BaseMessage>> MessageMap;

    //Class that creates messages
    class MessageManager
    {
        friend class MessageHandler;

        private:
            static MessageMap _messages;

            /*
            *   Replace this with your own behaviour for giving bad hash 
            */
            static void incorrectHash()
            {
                std::cout << "pin::MessageSystem : The hash of given arguments do not fit" << std::endl;
            }

            /*
            *   Replace this with your own behaviour for giving bad message name
            */
            static void incorrectMessage()
            {
                std::cout << "pin::MessageSystem : Message not found" << std::endl;
            }

        protected:

            template<class T, class... Args>
            static BaseMessage* listenToMessage(bool* handler, const std::string& messageName, void(T::*function)(Args... args), T* ownerPtr)
            {
                //Check if the message with messageName exists
                auto it = _messages.find(messageName);

                if (it != _messages.end())
                {
                    //Create temporary hash
                    std::size_t tmpHash = typeid(param_pack<Args...>).hash_code();

                    //Check the created hash with the hash of the message
                    if (it->second->haveSameParameterHash(typeid(param_pack<Args...>).hash_code()))
                    {
                        //Bind the function
                        static_cast<Message<Args...>*>(it->second.get())->bindFunction(handler, function, ownerPtr);

                        return it->second.get();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /*
                        * User tried to pass a different parameter pack that was passed to message when you created it. Pass your own behavior here
                        */
                        incorrectHash();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    /*
                    * User tried to find a message that does not exists, put your own behaviour here
                    */
                    incorrectMessage();

                }

                return nullptr;
        }

        template<class... Args>
        static void broadcastMessage(const std::string& messageName, Args... args)
        {
            //Check if the message with messageName exists
            auto it = _messages.find(messageName);

            if (it != _messages.end())
            {
                //Generated hash for current parameter pack
                std::size_t tmpHash = typeid(param_pack<Args...>).hash_code();

                //Check if its the right hash
                if (it->second->haveSameParameterHash(typeid(param_pack<Args...>).hash_code()))
                {
                    //If its right broadcast the message
                    static_cast<Message<Args...>*>(it->second.get())->broadcast(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                }
                else
                {
                    incorrectHash();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                incorrectMessage();
            }
        }

        public:

            template<class... Args>
            static void createMessage(const std::string& messageName)
            {
                _messages[messageName] = std::make_unique<Message<Args...>>(messageName);
            }
    };

    MessageMap MessageManager::_messages;

    //Class that can listen to messages or broadcast them
    class MessageHandler
    {
            private:
                bool _active;

                std::vector<BaseMessage*> _listenedMessages;
            public:

                MessageHandler():
                    _active(true){}

                ~MessageHandler()
                {
                    if (_active)
                        deleteHandler();
                }

                template<class T, class... Args>
                void listenToMessage(const std::string& messageName, void(T::*function)(Args... args), T* ownerPtr)
                {
                    //Vector of messages being listened to by this handler
                    _listenedMessages.emplace_back(MessageManager::listenToMessage(&_active, messageName, function, ownerPtr));
                }

                template<class... Args>
                void broadcastMessage(const std::string& messageName, Args... args)
                {
                    //Broadcast message
                    MessageManager::broadcastMessage(messageName, args...);
                }

                void deleteHandler()
                {
                    _active = false;

                    //All messages must clear their listeners - delete those who are inactive
                    for (auto& message : _listenedMessages)
                        message->clearListeners();
                }
    };
}
```

The **pin** prefix is just a prefix I use for my creations. The code is fully posted on github, also with some little tutorial for the use : [github link](https://github.com/Pinsius/pin-MessageSystem)

As I´m just a novice in the programming, I would like to hear some feedback from you guys. Especially the bad things, what should be improved. Thanks

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Clearly define the use case

When I think of "message systems", it's either message passing between different computers, processes, or threads. However, it seems that your message system only works within a single thread of code. Also, it doesn't really store and forward messages, it merely registers and calls callback functions. This is fine, and may be exactly what you want, but make this absolutely clear for potential users of your message system.

## Handles versus names

Your message system identifies message types by name. However, you have to programmatically register message types. Instead of using an unordered map to associate message types with names, why not have `MessageManager::createMessage<>()` return a reference to the `Message` object? This way, you can pass that reference to `listenToMessage()` and `broadcastMessage()`, instead of a name, and avoid doing map lookups every time.

## Avoid global state

Your `MessageMap` is a global variable. What happens if you have a program that links with multiple libraries, each of which uses your message system? They will all use the same `MessageMap`. This might result in conflicts.

You already have made it so that you have to declare `MessageManager` variables before you can listen to and send `Message`s. Why not make `MessageMap` a non-static member variable of `MessageManager`?

## Check for multiple registrations of the same name

Your code currently does not check if a program tries to call `MessageManager::createMessage<>()` twice with the same name. It will just overwrite the entry in the `MessageMap` with the second `Message` instance.
Either avoid using names at all, or check that you don't add the same name twice (or alternatively, allow double registrations, but only as long as they all register the exact same message type).

## `hash_code()` is not guaranteed to be unique

You are using `hash_code()` to check whether the type of a parameter pack is the same as that of a `Message`. However, while `hash_code()` guarantees that identical types get the same hash value, there is no guarantee that two different types get a different hash value.

If you avoid using message names, but rather have a reference to an actual `Message` object, then you could move functions like `listenToMessage()`, `broadcastMessage()` to the `Message` class. Then the compiler would exactly know the type of the parameter pack, without having to rely on run-time checks.

## Use `std::function<>` for callbacks

Instead of forcing callbacks to be pointers to member functions, and requiring
the user to specify both the member function and the object individually, use `std::function<>` to represent a callback function. The advantage is that it will accept any type of function as a callback, whether a named function, a lambda, or a member function (using `std::bind`). Make it like so:

```
template<class... Args>
void listenToMessage(const std::string& messageName, std::function<void(Args...)> callback)
{
    ...
}
```

To have a user specify a class member function as the callback, it has to be called like this:

```
Foo foo;
tut.listenToMessage("foo", std::bind(&Foo::test, foo));
```

But it makes it much easier to work with non-member functions or lambdas:

```
void non_member(int i) { std::cout << i; }
MessageManager::createMessage<int>("foo");
tut.listenToMessage("foo", non_member);
tut.listenToMessage("foo", [](int i){ std::cout << i; })
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! However I have some additional questions: 
1) About using names for associating with messages - How would you implement that? I mean, I can store the reference in some temporary variable in my program and pass this variable to every handler that needs to listen to my message? I thought that it would be more work, even though it sounds like bigger performance drop (but map lookup for listening is done only at the start), for broadcasting, I want to give user option to use 1 handler for whole communication, so even the option to broadcast multiple messages. Is it bad?

Comment: Good catch with the multiple message names, will absolutely dive into it. Also the global state, you mean to use a singleton? Or just a nonstatic variable? I know singleton is also not solving this solution. About the hash_code(), i have to think about replacement.

Comment: I would try to avoid using names at all. This decouples the actual `Message` type from its use when calling `listenToMessage()`, `broadcastMessage()` etc., so the compiler will not be able to do the type checking for you. Instead, make it like `auto intMessage = MessageManager::createMessage<int>()`, and for example add listeners using `tut.listenToMessage(intMessage, callback)`. Or even better, try to make it so you can do: `intMessage.listen(callback)`.

Comment: A singleton is also global state. Make the `MessageMap` a non-static variable.

Comment: The point with std::function is perfect, I will make it as an overload, so it would be not that difficult for member functions

Comment: About the returning the type for the message, I understand your point. However, for this approach I would need to store those returned variables somewhere, because : What if I will create dynamically objects that will start to listen to specific type of message during their creation? I would need to pass all of the desired "messages". At this point no references are needed, however it comes at price of the lookup performance.

Comment: I´ve added edit with "pseudo implementation" of the implementation without using the hash_code() function. The manipulation via the names is still present..

Comment: For completeness, the changes mentioned by Pins can be found at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/190603/2.